# python3 root-privileges for BLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, sudo

Why does [this python2-BLE-application](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics-CentralLabs/BlueSTSDK_Python#running-the-application-examples) need sudo-rights whereas [gatt-python](https://github.com/getsenic/gatt-python/tree/master/examples) doesn't?

Via both, you are able to communicate with a [microcontroller-board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-mcu-nucleo.html?querycriteria=productId=LN1847). (I've tested this with a [BLE-Extansion-board](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/ecosystems/stm32-open-development-environment/stm32-nucleo-expansion-boards/stm32-ode-connect-hw/x-nucleo-idb05a1.html).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gatt-python` uses DBus to talk to `bluetoothd`, which is itself running with elevated privileges. OTOH, the BlueST SDK uses [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy), which contains a small [helper application](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/blob/master/bluepy/bluepy-helper.c), and that directly talks to the Bluetooth adapter using the HCI protocol, which requires root privileges (and is actually not recommended anymore, as it will interfere with `bluetoothd`).